# How to call a dll file that is in client system using PHP?

Tags: php, dll

I want to call the dll that is available in client machine`(For example:C:\Program Files\Applicationname\example.dll)`.I am using windows environment.So No issues with using COM.
But I dont know how to create a object for the client's machine dll?I need a help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP has nothing to do here. You have to think of your question better. Or, even better, ask not the way you choose but goal. Though I doubt you we well see it.

Answer (score 0):

If this DLL is a COM object you may take a look at the [relevant section in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php). If it is a Win32 library you could use the [w32api_invoke_function](http://usphp.com/manual/en/function.w32api-invoke-function.php) but this extension is still experimental.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule php running on the server has no access to a dll/com component residing on the client.
You need a very special environment to do so. Either server and client are the same machine. Or the client machine exposes the component via [**D**COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model) (or its .net equivalent).

Comment: Thanks VolkerK.Do you have any examples for that even the server and application on the same machine?Because I am using XAMPP only.At least I want to test the application.